# How do I compare a string variable to a list of string variables in a Sympy matrix?

Tags: python, string, matrix, sympy

I'm trying to access a list of string variables in a matrix to compare to a user inputted string in an if/elif statement. I can't seem to get the access right as my code prints the 'else' statement and doesn't do what I want...

```
from sympy.interactive import printing 
printing.init_printing(use_latex = True)
from sympy import Eq, solve_linear_system, Matrix 
import sympy as sp

NumberString = "four"
EvenMatrix = Matrix(["two" ,"four" ,"six","eight" ,"ten"])
display(EvenMatrix)
OddMatrix = Matrix(["one", "three", "five", "seven", "nine"])
display(OddMatrix)

if (NumberString == EvenMatrix):
    display(NumberString)
    print('The NumberString is even.')
elif (NumberString == OddMatrix):
    display(NumberString)
    print('The NumberString is odd.')
else:
    print('wtf is going on?')
```

I'd like to compare the user input string to a list of strings in a matrices for cleaner code as opposed to something like this:

```
if (NumberString == EvenMatrix[0]) or (NumberString == EvenMatrix[1]) or (NumberString == EvenMatrix[2]) or (NumberString == EvenMatrix[3]) or (NumberString == EvenMatrix[4]):
    display(NumberString)
    print('The NumberString is even.')
elif (NumberString == OddMatrix[0]) or (NumberString == OddMatrix[1]) or (NumberString == OddMatrix[2]) or (NumberString == OddMatrix[3]) or (NumberString == OddMatrix[4]):
    display(NumberString)
    print('The NumberString is odd.')
else:
    print('wtf is going on?')
```

which, funnily enough, also doesn't work. I've done something similar with numbers before and it's worked fine but I'm not sure when it comes to strings. Please help.

Comment: You should convert elements in matrices to string objects and then compare. E.g. NumberString == str(EvenMatrix[0])  and so on. You can refer to my answer, too , link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72166834/1780667

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate through the odd and even matrices and check if the number string is there in the matrices. Also, compare the strings in matrices using str() method/constructor because the members of the matrix in "sympy" are converted into symbols even if you provide them as strings. I guess the display() is your own method. The solution code could be;

```
NumberString = "four"
EvenMatrix = Matrix(["two", "four", "six", "eight", "ten"])
OddMatrix = Matrix(["one", "three", "five", "seven", "nine"])
even = False
odd = False
for numberEven in EvenMatrix:
    if NumberString is str(numberEven):
        print('The NumberString is even.')
        even = True

for numberOdd in OddMatrix:
    if NumberString is str(numberOdd):
        print('The NumberString is odd.')
        odd = True

if even is False and odd is False:
    print("Wtf is going on")
```

Comment: Thanks for this! What if it was just a regular list of words I wanted to match and I couldn't use the numberEven/Odd?

Comment: If you use a regular list then a list comprehension would also do the job. e.g. resultEven = ["The NumberString is even" for string in evenlist if NumberString == string]. After that print(resultEven). resultEven will be empty if the NumberString is not present in evenlist. Similarly you can generate resultOdd.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that this is better handled with Python lists:

```
In [1]: NumberString = "four"
In [2]: evens=["two" ,"four" ,"six","eight" ,"ten"]
In [3]: odds=["one", "three", "five", "seven", "nine"]
In [4]: if NumberString in evens: print('even')
even
In [5]: if NumberString in evens: print('even')
   ...: elif NumberString in odds: print('odds')
   ...: else:print('wtf')
even

In [9]: NumberString='foo'
In [10]: if NumberString in evens: print('even')
    ...: elif NumberString in odds: print('odds')
    ...: else:print('wtf')
wtf
```

lists also have `index` method:

```
In [12]: evens.index('four')
Out[12]: 1
In [13]: odds.index('four')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [13] in <cell line: 1>
    odds.index('four')
ValueError: 'four' is not in list
```

With `numpy` arrays we can do:

```
In [14]: np.array(evens)=='four'
Out[14]: array([False,  True, False, False, False])
In [15]: np.nonzero(np.array(evens)=='four')
Out[15]: (array([1]),)
```

One problem with the `sympy` Matrix, is that the elements are not strings, but rather `symbols`.

```
In [86]: EvenMatrix
Out[86]: 
⎡ two ⎤
⎢     ⎥
⎢four ⎥
⎢     ⎥
⎢ six ⎥
⎢     ⎥
⎢eight⎥
⎢     ⎥
⎣ ten ⎦

In [88]: type(EvenMatrix[1])
Out[88]: sympy.core.symbol.Symbol
```

`sympy` requires some care to distinguish between strings, Python variables, and sympy symbols.  Even

```
four = sympy.symbols('four')
```

uses all 3 in different ways.